# Chosing categories rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

## Hopefully we have good rails developer who can definitely give correct answer! For 2 days I didn't receive any valid answer for my question

I will explain in a very simple example

Customer is offering product. When he pushes create it gives form. Choose a category. Once he chooses another form will pop up.

Depending on a category, form should have totally different attributes.I can't have Product.new for every category. Reason is they have different attributes(Logicaly true). So do I have to create 100 models for 100 categories

Categories are :  cars, apartments, coupons, books and many more

If you can give just one example I will be gratefull and call you expert

#### Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the answer you want, but you're going to need a lot of models.

The attributes associated with an apartment (square meters, utilities, floor of building) are completely different from the attributes associated with a car (make, model, mileage, condition) which are completely different from a book (title, author, publisher, edition, etc).  These items are so fundamentally different that there is no way to manage them in a single model.

That being said, there may be a core collection of attributes that might be associated with a product that is for sale (seller, price, terms).  You have basically two paths forward:

1. You could decide to use Single Table Inheritance.  In this case, you'd create an abstract class that defines the attributes that are common to all products that you are selling (seller, price, item).  You'd then add a "type" column to your database that would be used to determine what type of product it is (mapped to your categories), and define all of the possible attributes in a single table.
2. You could choose a core set of attributes, and use these as a part of any other object that is considered a product.  You'd have multiple tables that would have the full record for any given object.

Without knowing a lot of details about your application, it's hard to make a specific recommendation about which approach is right for you.  Your best bet at this point is to spend a lot of time on google with "single table inheritance rails" and "multi table inheritance rails" and figure out which one is right for you (though my gut says multi table).

Comment: Thanks Marc, you are first man who gave right direction. The reason why I was so concerned was I was trying to add items to the cart, and line_items can receive only product_id and cart_id. But my products have different attributes. So my 5 classes with different attributes should be connected to products class. How can I do that.

Comment: As I mentioned, you've got two choices.  Either your five classes can inherit from a single class (Single Table Inheritance), in which case your primary problem is to design a single table that works for all of them, or each of your classes can `has_one` core model that it is related to (Multi Table Inheritance).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're getting there. However, I wouldn't have a bunch of models like you're indicating in your question. I would say that you need a Product model and a Category model. The Category model will `belong_to Product`. The Product model would have many Categories. The Category model can use the `acts_as_tree` gem so that you can have categories and subcategories. Use javascript or jQuery (there was a recent Railscasts on this) to dynamically change and post a different field with a set of choices based on what was chosen.

EDIT:

I would have three Models; Product, Category, Specification

Product has many Categories
Product has many Specifications through Categories

Category belongs to Product
Category has many Specifications

Specification belongs to Category

This way I can create a product that has several categories. I can create several categories that have several specifications. Specifications are linked to the respective category. This will allow you to have three models and limited number of classes. Once your project is complete, new categories and specifications can be maintained by a web admin instead of a programmer.

Comment: I know about acts_as_tree I used it but when it comes bringing attributes for chosen category, from where i should bring it. Different attributes.

Comment: Gotcha. Couldn't you have an attributes model that belong_to Category. Using scopes, you could do product.category.attributes to see all of that product's attributes and when selecting a category for a new product, do category.attributes for the selected category to see what the attributes for that category is. You can then have something like a new product. The category is a car. the subcategory (acts_as_tree) is a sedan, attributes for the parent category_id would be A/C, Auto, Manual, Allow Wheels, etc.

Comment: Thanks for comment. class Book attr_accessors :isbn, :name   class Apartment attr_accessor :size, :location is this correct direction or I am wrong. 100 classes or something else I should do?

Comment: I wouldn't go that route. Doing that will create manual work whenever there is a new category type to be posted instead of a web interface for creating and adding new categories/attributes